# не работает event.preventDefault

Tags: jquery

```
function CheckExist(e) {
var phone = $('#phone').val();
event.preventDefault();

$.post('/ajax/CheckExistCustomer', {phone:phone}, function(data){
    if(data)
    {
        alert(12);
    }
});

}
```

Так event.preventDefault(); срабатывает
а если

```
 function CheckExist(e) {
var phone = $('#phone').val();


$.post('/ajax/CheckExistCustomer', {phone:phone}, function(data){
    if(data)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

}
```

то форма срабатывает в любом случае. 
Что делаю не так?

```
 <form id="NewCustomerForm" class="smart-form">

                        <fieldset>
                            <section class="col col-4">
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"       placeholder="Имя клиента">
                                </label>
                            </section>
                            <section class="col col-4">
                                <label class="input">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
                                </label>
                            </section>
                        </fieldset>
                        <footer>
                            <a href="/admin/customers/" class="btn btn-success noradius marbot25">
                                Отмена
                            </a>
                            <input type="submit" name="AddCustomer1" class="btn btn-info noradius" formaction="" formmethod="POST" value="Сохранить" onclick="CheckExist(this)">
                        </footer>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, пишите не

```
event.preventDefault();
```

а

```
e.preventDefault();
```

используя параметр функции `CheckExist`, который, я полагаю, и является event'ом.

Второе. Вызов `e.preventDefault();` внутри обработчика `$.post` смысла не имеет, так как произойдет гораздо позднее, к тому времени функция `CheckExist` давно закончит свою работу - `$.post` - метод, работающий асинхронно.

Попробуйте объяснить, что Вы хотите сделать, и Вам подскажут решение.

*Update*

В таком случае, Вам надо всегда вызывать `e.preventDefault();` в начале функции:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#NewCustomerForm").submit(CheckExist);

  function CheckExist(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    $.post('/ajax/CheckExistCustomer', {phone:phone}, function(data){
      if(data.alreadyExists) {
        alert("Phone already exists in the database.");
      } else {
        $("#NewCustomerForm")[0].submit();
      }
    });
  }

});
```

*Update 2*

`$("#NewCustomerForm")` и уберите `onclick="CheckExist(this)"` из html.

Comment: Есть Нажатие на submit. При нажатии на кнопку берется input. проверяется есть ли значение в базе и если есть то форма не шлется. и выдается сообщение что такой уже есть в базе.

Comment: $("NewCustomerForm").submit(CheckExist);

         function CheckExist(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    $.post('/ajax/CheckExistCustomer', {phone:phone}, function(data){
      if(data) {
        alert("Phone already exists in the database.");
      } else {
        $("NewCustomerForm")[0].submit();
      }
      });
      }   отправляется всегда

Comment: не `$("NewCustomerForm")`, a `$("#NewCustomerForm")`

Comment: изменил на form теперь при нажатии выдает ошибку  CheckExist is not defined(…)

Comment: @Durrasell Приведите полный код (и относящийся к делу html) - добавьте его в вопрос, а то мне сквозь монитор плохо видно, что у Вас там делается :).

Comment: Добавил в вопрос html код формы

Comment: @Durrasell смотрите *Update 2*

Comment: работает но форма отправляется GET-ом если нет в базе

Comment: Добавил в тег form метод. НО теперь в посте не передался параметр названия кнопки submit а по нему action срабатывал

Comment: @Durrasell - Вам придется перед `$("#NewCustomerForm")[0].submit();` записывать значение кнопки в `hidden` поле внутри формы.