# jquery кнопка открыть/скрыть блок

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#showHideText").click(function() {
    if ($("#hide-text").is(":hidden")) {

      $("#hide-text").show("slow");

    } else {

      $("#hide-text").hide("slow");

    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <img src="img/04.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <b class="catalog-item-price">300 р.</b>
  <div class="catalog-item-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hidden-text" id="hide-text">Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="showHideText" class="btn btn-info">Описание</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy">Купить</a>
</div>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <img src="img/05.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <b class="catalog-item-price">400 р.</b>
  <div class="catalog-item-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hidden-text" id="hide-text">Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Описание</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy">Купить</a>
</div>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <img src="img/06.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <b class="catalog-item-price">500 р.</b>
  <div class="catalog-item-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hidden-text" id="hide-text">Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Описание</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy">Купить</a>
</div>
```

Есть ли способ, чтобы был один скрипт для всех кнопок? Или мне каждый раз придется копировать `jquery` и менять `ID`?

Comment: Конечно можно, завязаться на класс вместо id.

Comment: все равно не очень понимаю, можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
    if ($(this).prev().find(".hidden-text").is(":hidden")) {
      $(this).prev().find(".hidden-text").show("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).prev().find(".hidden-text").hide("slow");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <img src="img/04.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <b class="catalog-item-price">300 р.</b>
  <div class="catalog-item-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hidden-text" id="hide-text">Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="showHideText" class="btn btn-info">Описание</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy">Купить</a>
</div>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <img src="img/05.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <b class="catalog-item-price">400 р.</b>
  <div class="catalog-item-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hidden-text" id="hide-text">Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Описание</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy">Купить</a>
</div>
<div class="catalog-item">
  <img src="img/06.jpg" alt="" width="306" height="206">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
  <b class="catalog-item-price">500 р.</b>
  <div class="catalog-item-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hidden-text" id="hide-text">Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum.</span></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Описание</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-buy">Купить</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `if ($(".hidden-text").is(":hidden")) {` - ?

Comment: Согласен странное условие, но сильно переделывать пример не стал

Comment: оно неправильное, так как проверяет видимость только первого элемента в выборке

Comment: обратно не закрывает

Comment: @АртёмХрещиков в песочнице нет такой проблемы, не закрывает на сайте?

Comment: @Дмитрий проблема есть - закройте первый текст, а потом попробуйте закрыть второй или третий; и я уже написал - почему

Comment: @Дмитрий, обрати внимание, если один из разделов свернут последующие не работают...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".catalog-item .btn.btn-info").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".catalog-item").find(".hidden-text").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: работает, но кидает вверх

Comment: @АртёмХрещиков Пардон, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

И да, не нужно на странице использовать 100-500 блоков с одинаковыми id, на то есть классы.

```
$(".catalog-item .btn.btn-info").click(function (e) {
  $(this).closest(".catalog-item").find(".hidden-text").toggle("slow");
  return false;
});
```

e.preventDefault() не всегда отрабатывает.

Comment: "e.preventDefault() не всегда отрабатывает" - приведите, пожалуйста, пример

Comment: Случается, что e.preventDefault() вызывают не первым действием, сам видел такие примеры. И в итоге из-за асинхрона успевал отработать переход по ссылке.

Comment: "вызывают не первым действием" - это не имеет никакого значения.  "сам видел" - Вы неправильно интерпретируете то, что Вы видели.  "из-за асинхрона успевал отработать" - это не лезет ни в какие ворота. Пожалуйста, не способствуйте распространению "культа грузовых самолетов" в программировании.

Comment: Окей, больше не буду. Однако вот ссылка на то. о чём я говорил. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595991/293639

Comment: Надо же, это мой ответ! Если Вы внимательно посмотрите, в чем там дело, то увидите, что ошибка автора вопроса была в вызове `preventDefault` внутри асинхронного колбэка. Использование `return false;` в том же месте было бы так же неправильно.

Comment: Согласен. Больше спорить не стану. ))